# Capacitive Touch Controller Help

Tags: hardware, touchscreen

hoping somebody can point me in the right direction. I've done some research but feel a bit stuck.
My intention is to use an Android Tablet I found on Ebay as a Homeassitant dashboard, bought it with a bit of Unknown other than it is a Media Wave MW22-A32 running Android 4.4. Got it and started messing with it and there is no upgrade path to any version of Android above 4.4 Android. Decided to order an LCD controller for it, which works great so far, got my Rasberry Pi Zero W plugged in and it displays just fine.
My challenge is the Capacitive Touch Digitizer that is in the Android Tablet. I've done some digging and found the datasheets for V1.0 and V1.3, I have V1.0, but that's where I get a bit lost. So to the Question, I have multiple Raspberry Pi Zero W V1.1 and a P13 Model B+, how would I go about getting the digitizer connected to either one of these Pi's?

[22" Android Touchscreen](https://www.ebay.com/itm/304788408068)

[LCD Controller HR215WU1-120](https://www.ebay.com/itm/163716126973?m)

[Capacitive Digitizer Images](https://imgur.com/a/iruCTBc)

[V1.0 DataSheet](https://285624.selcdn.ru/syms1/medialibrary/a62/a62d6e48c314475824c372c9f25118b5/ed0594096d033252e75859af1c351950.pdf)

[V1.3 DataSheet](https://www.szzxv.com/static/upload/file/20220330/1648627858438358.pdf)

Comment: Thanks, should be fixed now.

Comment: Ok, fixed for real this time.

Comment: The data sheet gives arm processor only I2C connection. Drivers may be available on GitHub. It can be connected to the Raspberry Pi. The drivers may be a problem.